# Add more to PlaceHolderMain (Custom)

Tags: 2010, web-part, master-page

I made a master page and created a new page from it. In the PlaceHolderMain I added a few WebPartZones and then in the browser filled them with CEWPs and filled the CEWPs with content. Now I go back to SPD to add more WebPartZones to the PlaceHolderMain (Custom) I seem to be locked out of adding things. I can make changes to inside the existing WebPartZones and to the CEWPs but nothing outside of it. Any idea how I can "unlock" this again to add more so I dont have to "Default to Masters Default".

Comment: what do you mean by "outside"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default when you open a web part page and a page layout in SharePoint designer it's opened in safe mode which means you can only change the areas which you can also change in the browser.

What you want instead it to right click the page layout and select Edit File in Advanced Mode:
[image]
This will allow you to add more web part zones and other markup (remember to check out the file first)

Comment: Oh, we answered at the same time, but yours has a schnazzy picture... you win sir.

Comment: It was a tough decision but ultimately the picture was more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Click "Advanced Mode" in the ribbon?

Comment: Yeah, but you have the easy solution when it's already opened "wrongly" and you beat me by 4 seconds ... so Jonathan decides who wins